# Operator in variable affectation

Tags: shell, scripting, ksh

I'm trying to understand the syntax of an existing ksh script. I came across the following line:

```
HOME_APP=${HOME_APP:-/app}
```

What does it mean?

Comment: In addition to the answer, there are other parameter expansions available. Refer https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: I'm sure there's a better duplicate available, but I'm having trouble finding an appropriate one.

Comment: That's good enough for me. It does what I thought it did, but I wanted to be sure there was nothing tricky going on. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there must be a duplicate for this, but `:-` is used to supply a default value for the expansion when `HOME_APP` is unset or null.

```
$ unset HOME_APP
$ echo "${HOME_APP:-/app}"
/app
$ HOME_APP=
$ echo "${HOME_APP:-/app}"
/app
$ HOME_APP=/opt
$ echo "${HOME_APP:-/app}"
/opt
```